# Method returns NodeBuffer instead of Elem and that violates the type checking rule

Tags: xml, scala

There are 2 methods, both return xml:

```
 def method1 = 
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope>
      <soap:Header>
        {Elem(....)}
      </soap:Header>
    </soap:Envelope>

 def method2 = 
  <someXml>
    //.......
  </someXml>
```

And there is one more method which gets Elem:

```
def method3(a: Elem) = //....

val xml1 = method1
val xml2 = method2

method3(xml1) //error
method3(xml2) //ok
```

It says `method1` returns `NodeBuffer` and it can't accept it, whereas `method2` returns `Elem` and that's perfectly fine.

Why is that? What do I do about it?

Comment: Could you pleas provide minimal compilable code sample to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @senia, there you go.

Comment: *Minimal* code sample would be `def method1 = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root />`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
scala> def method1 = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root />
method1: scala.xml.NodeBuffer
```

In `method1` you are trying to create not a `xml` with a `XML declaration`, but 2 `Node`s: [Processing instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction) (scala type [ProcInstr](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.xml.ProcInstr)) and `Elem`:

```
scala> <?abc attr1="v1" attr2="v2" ?>
res0: scala.xml.ProcInstr = <?abc attr1="v1" attr2="v2" ?>
```

Sequence of 2 nods gives you a collection of nodes - `NodeBuffer`:

```
scala> <a/><b/>
res0: scala.xml.NodeBuffer = ArrayBuffer(<a/>, <b/>)
```

Actually you can't use processing instruction `xml` manually:

```
scala> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: xml is reserved
```

Just remove it.

If you need XML declaration in serialized version you should use `XML.write` or `XML.save` with `xmlDecl = true`:

```
import xml.XML
val myXml = <root />
val writer = new java.io.StringWriter
XML.write(writer, myXml, "utf-8", xmlDecl = true, doctype = null)
writer.toString
// <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
// <root/>
```

Comment: This is xml for a rest service call. Remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` even though it must in the result xml?

Comment: But I need not only naked xml declaration but also other xml. That's why I'm using built-in Scala xml.

Comment: @Alex: second parameter of `write` and `save` is `node`. In my case it's `<root />`

Comment: if there any way to return xml itself (preferably `Elem`, at least `NodeBuffe`r, but not string) from `writer`?

Comment: @Alex: You can't get `Elem` with `XML declaration` in scala. Take a look at [`Elem`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.xml.Elem) constructor: there is no place to add  declaration. `Elem` could be a `child` of another `Elem` - how could it be possible with `XML declaration` in child `Elem`?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to convert the final assembled XML to an XHTML string.

I've done this with the Play framework where I use Scala's built-in support for XML in place of the so-called Twirl templates (well, I still use their `Html` wrapper, but everything else is pure XML). The below allows you to preserve the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` line, required in OP's case and many others, e.g. generating an XML sitemap.

```
import scala.xml.Xhtml

Html{
s"""
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
${Xhtml.toXhtml(
  <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  ...
)}
"""
}
```

Just make that the very last step before sending to client. `toXhtml` can of course take passed in XML (i.e. don't have to manually define in place as I've done above)